# Grid panel under a tab panel does not collpase/expand properly

Tags: javascript

I've added a grid panel to a tab panel, and made it collapsible: true,
how ever it does not collapse properly. When collapsed, all rows with data get hidden which are expected, but the whole grid panel does not get resized, it still takes as much space as  when it's expanded, so I see some white spaces in the grid. Does anybody have similar experiences or have any solutions?

```
initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;

    me.initialConfig = Ext.apply({
        trackResetOnLoad: true
    }, me.initialConfig);

    Ext.applyIf(me, {
        defaults: {
            fieldStyle: 'font-weight: bold;',
            labelWidth: 70
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'tabpanel',
                flex: 1,
                collapseFirst: false,
                manageHeight: false,
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        title: 'View EIR',
                        layout: {
                            type: 'vbox',
                            align: 'stretch'
                        },




                me.processEirActivityGrid({
                                        xtype: 'eirActivityPanel',
                                        height: '',
                                        id: 'eirActivityGrid',
                                        itemId: 'eirActivityGrid',
                                        focusOnToFront: false,
                                        forceFit: false,
                                        flex: 1
                                    })


                        ]
                    },

    });
}

processEirActivityGrid: function(config) {
    config.data = this.data;
    return config;
},
```